# Pdf blank Export to Blob

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, model-view-controller, blob

I have files stored in mysql in a blob field.
When I want to export these data to pdf, I get empty, although the pdf maintains its size and quantity of page, the content is totally empty

the code for download PDF

```
        HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        responseMsg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(unFile.blob);
       responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = unFile.Name;
        responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
```